# For $C>0$ such that $\frac{1}{C} \leq \frac{a_j}{b_j} \leq C$ for all $j$ large, then either both series diverge or both series converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_j a_j$ and $\sum_j b_j$ be series of positive terms.  Prove that if there is a constant $C>0$ such that $$\frac{1}{C} \leq \frac{a_j}{b_j} \leq C$$ for all $j$ large, then either both series diverge or both series converge.

For this problem I feel like I need to use a contradiction. I tried to say that assume $a_j$ converges and $b_j$ diverges. Then $a_j$ go to some limit and $b_j$ either go to infinity or they oscillate and diverge. For the goes to infinity case, it is straightforward to show that $$\frac{1}{C} \leq \frac{limit}{\infty} \leq C$$ so $$\frac{1}{C} \leq 0 \leq C$$ and we have a contradiction since we can't find a C where this is true.

My problem is for the oscillation divergence. I can't figure out how to disprove that case.

Comment: You can use comparison test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the entire inequality by $b_j$ and apply the comparison test.

Comment: The comparison test requires a convergent series of non-negative terms. We can't assume that either $a_j$ or $b_j$ are non-negative.

Comment: @clay did you read the question?

Comment: The question specifies positive terms. I missed that! Thanks!